# BUG - Tags at bottom of question page unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Found a "bug". At the bottom of question pages, in the dark bar, you've got the text 'Browse other questions tagged' and then the question tags get repeated. But these tags are white text on a white background. More specifically this CSS:

```
.bottom-notice .post-tag:not(.moderator-tag), .bottom-notice .required-tag:not(.moderator-tag) 
{
    color: white !important;
}
```

For some reason the regular color #999 gets overwritten by an `!important` tag. On hover the text becomes readable, because the background turns red.

[image: GDSE bottom page tags]

Comment: I think someone is playing around with The CSS. I noticed something similar with `<kbd>` tags the other day but it fixed itself before I could post anything here. Not sure why though.

Comment: @Oded: still experiencing this issue, even after clearing my browser cache.

Comment: Will take another look. I though this was a different (already fixed) issue. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it has been like this for at least a year.

Thanks for reporting - this is fixed and will be deployed soon.

Comment: Thank you. I had noticed it before, but it wasn't a really big deal.

Comment: Sharp eye then, @PieBie! :D

Comment: Hurray, it's been fixed!